# How to reset an arraylist when restarting my program in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a snake game in javafx and I've run into a problem. My game works just fine, but I do not know how to reset my game (without closing the program and re running it). I have created a reset method that resets all variables back to their initial values, and they all work other than the snake itself. When I click the ENTER key (my reset button), my snake gets respawned at its initial location but, the old snakebody is still there and my new snake can't grow. I believe this is because I'm resetting my arraylist that stores the rectangles that make up the snake.

Here's a snippet of my code that affects the resetting:

```
public void reset() {
    SnakeBody.setX(150); //Reset the snake to its starting position
    SnakeBody.setY(150);

    Food.setX(600); //Reset the food to the starting position
    Food.setY(600);

    rightSpeed = 0;//Reset all speeds, making the snake still when the game resets
    upSpeed = 0;
    leftSpeed = 0;
    downSpeed = 0;
    SnakeSpeed = 4;

    if (canvas.getChildren().contains(SpeedBoost)) { //Removing the speedboost if it is in the canvas at the time of resetting.
        canvas.getChildren().remove(SpeedBoost);
    }

    if (canvas.getChildren().contains(ScoreMultiplier)) {
        canvas.getChildren().remove(ScoreMultiplier);
    }

    score = 0; //Resetting score.
    Score.setText("Score: " + score);

    Snakes.clear(); //Clearing the snake arraylist

    Snakes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(); //Re initializing the same arraylit
    for (int i = Snakes.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {

                Snakes.get(i).setX(Snakes.get(i - 1).getX());
                Snakes.get(i).setY(Snakes.get(i - 1).getY());

            }

    Objects(); //The method that creates the food, speed boost and multiplier.


}
```

Also, here's the arraylist that makes the snake:

```
public ArrayList<Rectangle> makeSnakeBodies() {

    ArrayList<Rectangle> joints = new ArrayList<>();

    int x = 150;
    int y = 150;

    SnakeBody = new Rectangle(x, y, 30, 30);
    SnakeBody.setFill(Color.GOLD);
    SnakeBody.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
    joints.add(SnakeBody);

    return joints;

}
```

I am new to Java, so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: Full Code: https://pastebin.com/jpFf4wuq

Comment: You probably haven't reset the state of your scene. You've probably got some layouts that are initially empty and get filled during the initialisation or while the game is running. You need to restore that state too. Any animation classes used may require custom treatment too. We can't really post good answers here without seeing more of your code. (Code necessary to answer the question is required to be part of the question itself; a pastebin link is not sufficient...)

Comment: @kleopatra, in the minimal reproducible example link you posted, one strategy was divide and conquer, meaning to remove all the code until you're left with what your sure causes the problem. I have already removed everything that doesn't affect my issue, only leaving my reset method (which is what I'm asking about) and my arraylist(what is causing the issue). So I don't see a problem with my post. I do concede your point about naming conventions.

Comment: @fabian, another user said I had to move my arraylist to somewhere else in my code. Do you think it should go inside my initialize method? Or in my animation timer? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not an example doesn't compile as-is, let alone run - so not reproducible .. as was already noted by Mark in the comments to his try of an answer ;) Do provide a [mcve] or see your question closed (most probable, has my vote on it, as you might have guessed <g>)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
joints.clear():
```

See [official documentation of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--)

However make sure you're reseting a list which is stored as an internal state of your objects (it should be declared as a datafield somewhere)

I couldnt see from the code where exactly you do this, but all in all the `clear` method of the list removes all the elements.

One more suggestion, you'll probably have to re-render the UI so that you'll be able to see that the old list is not drawn anymore

Comment: When I try to change it to joints.clear(); I get an error saying it cannot find the variable joints. Is this because my arraylist is after (and outside) my primary stage (public void start)?

Comment: Yes, variable 'joints' currently exists only inside the method `makeSnakeBodies` which means that you should somewhere store this arraylist somewhere otherwise it won't be preserved. Its not shown in the code... In general you shoud decouple the internal state from the representational (UI) logic, it will lead to better design

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, are you saying I should move the arraylist inside my public void start?

Comment: I don't see 'start' method so I can't really answer that :) I'm just saying that there should be a class that has a data-field with all the 'pieces' of the snake body, and when you reset - you should go to that class and call 'clear' on that arraylist. you might indeed slightly refactor the code...

Comment: I posted my full code in my post, could you show me where the arraylist should go instead?